# JAVA массив байт в объект

Tags: java, исключения, сериализация, netty, поток-ввода

При чтении `ObjectInputStream` получаю `EOFException`, думал сначала что это как метка, что достигнут конец, но объект так и не считался?

Поэтому нужен другой способ!

```
   @Override
public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) throws Exception {
    ByteBuf in = (ByteBuf) msg;
    byte[] buf = new byte[in.readableBytes()];
    in.readBytes(buf);

    Packet packet = null;

    try(ByteArrayInputStream b = new ByteArrayInputStream(buf)){
        try(ObjectInputStream o = new ObjectInputStream(b)){
            packet = (Packet) o.readObject();

        }catch (EOFException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    if (!packet.getKey().isEmpty() && packet.getValue() != null){
        try {
            this.cache.addItem(packet.getKey(),packet.getValue());
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch (OutOfMemoryError e){
            this.cache.saveRelease();

        }
    }
    if(!packet.getKey().isEmpty() && packet.getValue() == null){
        ctx.write(this.cache.getItem(packet.getKey()));
    }
}
```

Comment: Экспериментируя понял две вещи 1) что в bytebuf 2 байта конца потока 1 от сокета второй самого bytebuf 2)что перед передачей информации в пото пишуться еще какие-то байты Из-за этого у меня вылетает EOFE и Не может конвертироваться маасив байтов в объект. Что за байты перед переданной мной информацией и фиксированного они количества?

Answer (score 1):

Лично я использую такие методы:

```
public static byte[] objectToByteArray(Object obj) throws Exception
{
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);
    try
    {
        oos.writeObject(obj);
        return baos.toByteArray();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw e;
    }
    finally
    {
        oos.close();
        baos.close();
    }
}

public static Object byteArrayToObject(byte[] byteArray) throws Exception
{
    ByteArrayInputStream baos = new ByteArrayInputStream(byteArray);
    ObjectInputStream oos = new ObjectInputStream(baos);
    try
    {
        return oos.readObject();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw e;
    }
    finally
    {
        oos.close();
        baos.close();
    }
}
```

Можете попробовать:

```
try
{
    packet = (Packet) byteArrayToObject(buf);
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    //Exceptions handling
}
```

Comment: Экспериментируя понял две вещи

1) что в bytebuf 2 байта конца потока 1 от сокета второй самого bytebuf

2)что перед передачей информации в пото пишуться еще какие-то байты
 
Из-за этого у меня вылетает EOFE и Не может конвертироваться маасив байтов в объект.
Что за байты перед переданной мной информацией и фиксированного они количества?